# params[:action] for mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to create a helper that will be used in the mailer class. That helper will render some output in all the email template.
Output of that helper will depend on which method of mailer class is called.

Basically What I am looking for is a kind of params[:action] in mailer. I don't know if it is possible or not.

Could any one help??